# Use form to check whether someone is older than given age

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access

I've tried this code in order to get my form to tell me whether a customer is older than 16 or 18 if they're trying to hire a R16 or R18 movie.

HireMovieID and HireCustomerID are two text boxes on my form. MovieID and CustomerID are columns within my MovieList and CustomerInfo tables.

```
    Private Sub HireCommand_Click()

If Not IsNumeric(HireMovieID) Or Not IsNumeric(HireCustomerID) Then
    MsgBox "Error: Not a number"
    Exit Sub
End If

Dim MovieRating As String
Dim CustomerDOB As Date
Dim Age16Check As Date
Dim Age18Check As Date

MovieRating = DLookup("[Rating]", "MovieList", "MovieID = [Forms]![HireForm]![HireMovieID]")
CustomerDOB = DLookup("[DOB]", "CustomerInfo", "CustomerID = [Forms]![HireForm]![HireCustomerID]")
Age16Check = DateSerial(-16, Month(Date), Day(Date))
Age18Check = DateSerial(-18, Month(Date), Day(Date))


If MovieRating = "R16" Then
    If CustomerDOB > Age16Check Then
        MsgBox "This customer is too young to hire this movie"
    Else: MsgBox "This customer is old enough to hire this movie"
    End If
ElseIf MovieRating = "R18" Then
    If CustomerDOB > Age18Check Then
        MsgBox "This customer is too young to hire this movie"
    Else: MsgBox "This customer is old enough to hire this movie"
    End If
Else: MsgBox "This movie does not have a restricted rating, thus this customer may hire this DVD"
End If

End Sub
```

**EDIT:** When I run this code, if I have an R16 movie selected, it will say that all the customers are too young to hire it? How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance for your help! :)

Comment: Do you have an unbound MovieID and CustomerID control on your form?

Comment: Yes those are my HireCustomerID and HireMovieID.

Comment: [.Find method of Range object in Excel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx)